# Daemon process can't import package

Tags: python, linux, macos, daemon

I have a TCP server and this server runs a test script called `ios_aio.py`. If I start the TCP server manually via terminal and run the test everything works, and it works if I launch it via a shell script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/wirelesseasy/Desktop/jiz/Chamber1Utils/servers_DevicesModules
python  /Users/wirelesseasy/Desktop/jiz/Chamber1Utils/servers_DevicesModules/TCPServer.py
```

In both situations I start the server and the test runs without any problem.

However, if I set the server run as a daemon process, the server still starts but when it loads the test it can't import the package. Is this some permission issue?

The way I run it as daemon is here:

```
import os, sys
import getpass
import subprocess as sp

def find_server(path,server):
    for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
        if server in f:
            return os.path.abspath(r)

def create_agent(cmd,shell):
    import plistlib
    import tempfile
    import datetime

    d = { 'Label':'org.wirelesseasy.daemontcp',
          'ProgramArguments':[cmd, shell],
          'RunAtLoad':True,
          'KeepAlive':True

          }

    output_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    try:
        plistlib.writePlist(d, output_file)
        output_file.seek(0)
        f = open('org.wirelesseasy.daemontcp.plist','w')
        f.write( output_file.read() )
        f.close()
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        output_file.close()
    return os.path.abspath('./org.wirelesseasy.daemontcp.plist')




def create_shell(server_path,cmd='python '):
    sh = open('daemonServer.sh', 'w')
    sh.write('#!/bin/bash\n')
    sh.write('cd '+ server_path + '\n')

    sh.write(cmd + ' '+server_path+'/TCPServer.py')
    sh.close()
    shellpath = os.path.abspath('daemonServer.sh')

    p = sp.Popen(['chmod','777',shellpath], stdout=sp.PIPE)

    while p.poll() is None:
        pass

    return os.path.abspath('daemonServer.sh')



def setagent(agent,dest):
    cmd = 'cp '+ agent +' '+dest
    cmd = cmd.split()
    p = sp.Popen(cmd,stdout=sp.PIPE)
    while p.poll() is None:
        pass
    res = []
    for i in p.stdout:
        res.append(i)
    return res



def launchagent(dest,agent):
    agent = agent.split('/')
    agent = agent[len(agent)-1]
    # agent = agent.strip('.plist')
    os.chdir(dest)
    cmd = 'launchctl load '+agent
    p = sp.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=sp.PIPE)
    res = []
    while p.poll() is None:
        pass
    for i in p.stdout:
        res.append(i)
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cur_dir  = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    server_path = find_server(cur_dir+'/..', 'TCPServer.py')

    shell = create_shell(server_path)
    agent = create_agent('/bin/sh', shell)
    print agent

    user = getpass.getuser()
    dest = '/Users/{}/Library/LaunchAgents'.format(user)

    setagent(agent,dest)
    res = launchagent(dest,agent)
    print res
```

The error is simple, it's just can't find those modules the test script imports

The original way is start the TCP server, and in the client, it send command to TCP server, inside the server, it creates a subprocess called ios_aio.py. This works for manually starts the server or using the shell,  but when I use launchctl to set it as daemon, those packages for ios_aio.py can't be imported

Comment: If you could give us the error you're getting. The answers we can give you would become much more substantial.

Comment: The error is simple, it's just can't find those modules the test script imports

Comment: @Jialang Zhou Have the modules been added to the global search path?

Comment: @ateesdalejr i don't think so. In the server, I already use os.setdir to change the working directory to the directory of the test. Cause if I use the shell or manually start the server and run, it works. Just crashed when I set it as daemon

Comment: @ateesdalejr Those packages need to import is added to the global search path cause I can import them from other directory